# How can I find why a user was suspended?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

I recently found that one of the helpful users was suspended. Is there any way to find out exactly why they were suspended?

Their profile says nothing except:

> This account is temporarily suspended for rule violations. The suspension period ends on Dec 13 at 19:34.

Answer (score 26):

It says why:

> for rule violations

There really is no need for anyone outside of the user and moderator team to know any more.

Comment: For rule violation tells absolutely nothing. It is the same as "he was arrested because he has done something wrong". As for there is no need to know, this sounds like a secret society, where some higher power keeps things secret.

Comment: Exactly. That's the point. It is a private matter between the user and the moderators. It is not a public matter.

Comment: So a moderator can just decide to suspend a person based on some private matter? Can a user object to these private matters from the moderator? Sorry for these questions.

Comment: To an extent. The record is there for other moderators and Stack Exchange staff to see. So if a moderator does that, there is a historical record to see. If the moderator acted in bad faith they can certainly be removed as result (not that this normally happens).

Comment: Additionally, a user can _always_ write to the Stack Exchange community team directly to complain about unfairness of this kind - that's what the [contact us](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) link in the footer is for - this is feedback that doesn't go to moderators directly.

Comment: got it, thanks for an explanation.

Comment: No problem - hope things are clearer now, and that they seem reasonable ;)

Comment: @SalvadorDali: would you rather that if you *did* do something wrong and you cheated, that *everyone* on Stack Overflow got to see that?